# Restore Ubuntu-Tweak from recover cd or external HD

Tags: restore, ubuntu-tweak, recovery-mode

I've been trying to repair my system after it froze during a session using Ubuntu-Tweak. I'm aware that it only saves the settings and not the files, so my question is:

**Can I restore it from another hard-drive or live CD?**

I'm fairly new to Linux, but I'm gaining ground after getting "greedy" with all the possibilities included with the open source software. It's part of my learning process. I break it, then I learn how to fix it (sometimes). I've searched to no avail for a solution so any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Jeremy

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  Do you mean you want to undo whatever settings you changed with ubuntu-tweak?

Comment: Yes, it has a back-up option which probably works if your able to start it. I wasn't able to log in. For some reason my rescue mode never worked after install, but I never needed it and didn't realize until I needed it. I was using it to clean up a big mess (removing excess files after installing Kubuntu alongside Ubuntu accidentally). I had a launch menu that was being populated with items and sub-items. Nothing I tried helped and it's was a quite a mess I caused. I thought I'd try Ubuntu-Tweak but other issues + the strain of Ubuntu-Tweak crashed my computer.

Comment: I just finished an ugly fix. I used an external drive I use to install Ubuntu. Once I gained access to the files I installed U.T. on it and made some back-ups. Next I copied the broke system's backups and replaced them with the external b-up's, imported the old backups into the install drive, then cp'ed them into the old OS. I just gained access, but have some bugs to work out. I'm sure there's a better way and hoped someone had encountered/fixed it already. Thanks for your reply. I'm sure I'll be back to help if I can and get a little advice.

Answer (score 1):

OP solved problem:

> I just finished an ugly fix. I used an external drive I use to install Ubuntu. Once I gained access to the files I installed U.T. on it and made some back-ups. Next I copied the broke system's backups and replaced them with the external b-up's, imported the old backups into the install drive, then cp'ed them into the old OS. I just gained access, but have some bugs to work out. I'm sure there's a better way and hoped someone had encountered/fixed it already. Thanks for your reply. I'm sure I'll be back to help if I can and get a little advice.